# PHP query will not update record in database

Tags: php, mysql

Hello I am trying to subtract the accepted bid which is an int from the job table and subtract from the credit from customer table but for some reason it will not update the credit row. Any ideas why this is?

tables: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3bjbe.jpg

```
<?php
session_start();
require 'config.php';


$id = $_SESSION['login_user'];
$jobid    = $_POST['job_id'];
$poster_id    = $_POST['poster_id'];
$accepted_bidder    = $_POST['accepted_bidder'];
$accepted_bid    = $_POST['accepted_bid'];

$query   = "SELECT credit FROM `customer` WHERE email_adress = '$.id'";

$success = $conn->query($query);

$updated_credit = $success - $accepted_bid
echo $updated_credit;


$query2   = " UPDATE job SET start_escrow = '1' WHERE  job_id = '$jobid'";
$success2 = $conn->query($query2);

$query3   = " UPDATE credit SET credit_amount = '$updated_credit' WHERE  credit_id = '$poster_id'";
$success3 = $conn->query($query3);

$poster_id = $_POST['poster_id'];

if (!$success) {
    die("Couldn't enter data: ".$conn->error);

}
 header("location: myjobs.php");

echo "Thank You For Contacting Us <br>";

$conn->close();




?>
```

Comment: The only output is "Thank you for contacting us" so Im assuming updated_credit is empty for some reason,

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have the autocommit enabled? If not, after each `$conn->query(...)` you have to specify `$conn->commit` or you can create a transaction and only at the end you give that code

Comment: Yes all the other queries where I have used this have worked and also when I echo the updated credit there is no output.

Comment: I don't understand why you wrote '$.id' instaed '$id'. Try to remove the spaces before the UPDATE statement and in WHERE  credit_id and WHERE job_id (you have two spaces between words) and then update the code. Can you post the php_error_log? The query is not executed because probably updated_credit has nothing since the is no variable named $.id but it should be $id

Comment: yes this was a temporary suggestion someone told me to do which didn't work and removed after as it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

## First thing first, you must sanitize your data

You can use the PHP filter function to get you started, or create your own custom function to handle sanitization.

## Example With php filter function

*email - filter_input()*:

```
filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'form_input_email_name_here', FILTER_SANITIZE_NAME );
```

*email - filter_val()*:

```
filter_var( $email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL );
```

## For Integer, use casting

```
$id = (int) $_POST['id'];
```

Or, create a custom function with preg_replace() to sanitize the data

```
// Will accept full names like: john doe, john doe smith
function sanitize_name( $data )
{
    $full_name_regex = "/^([a-z]{2,20})([\s])([a-z]{2,20})(\s[a-z]{2,20})?$/i";

    return preg_replace( $full_name_regex, '', $data );
}
```

**Note:** The above snippets are just demo, to show you what am talking about.

## Now, to your question - can't update the credit table

```
$query3   = " UPDATE credit SET credit_amount = '$updated_credit' WHERE  credit_id = '$poster_id'";
$success3 = $conn->query($query3);
```

This maybe as a result of the following:

1. credit_id = '$poster_id'; it may be that '$poster_id' does not exists in the credit table, to check if this is true, do:  `var_dump( $success3->rowCount );`

if `$success3->rowCount` is less than 1, then it means that `'$poster_id'` does not exists in the credit table, that's why the update failed.

Or, in other to be sure about this, do a select query and examine the result:

```
$sql = "SELECT credit_amount FROM credit WHERE credit_amount = '$updated_credit'";

$success3 = $conn->query( $sql );
```

Check if the query return any result

```
var_dump( $success3 );
```

So, if `var_dump( $success3 )` is empty, then this shows that `'$poster_id'` doesn't exists in the credit table.

One more thing, I'm not sure about this line: `'$.id'`

```
$query = "SELECT credit FROM `customer` WHERE email_adress = '$.id'";
```

It should be: `$id`